# can run in emulator but can't build apk in flutter android studio with error Task:image_picker_android:testDebugUnitTest FAILED

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

The flutter project can run command `flutter run`  but can't run flutter build apk / release one, returning with errors in android studio after i run  with --stacktrace, i found error Task:image_picker_android:testDebugUnitTest FAILED on image_picker: ^0.8.5+1 latest version with several test failed

```
 Building with sound null safety 



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 35s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           36.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.1219], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.9.51)
    X Visual Studio 2019 or later is required.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

after i run command   `./gradlew build --stacktrace`  i get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i just run command

> ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace

instead of

> ./gradlew build --stacktrace

and it works fine